# MATLAB - Only first column variable gets read when generating function

Tags: excel, matlab, file-io, import, user-defined-functions

it might be a basic question. I am a beginner.

When I am trying to import an excel file with 5 columns and row 1 as column header, and generating a function for doing the same, MATLAB is not generating 5 variable as per the column headers, but only one variable and that too with the default name, ans.

Kindly help.

Here is the code:

```
function [Date,Open,High,Low,Close] = importfile(workbookFile,sheetName,startRow,endRow)

% If no sheet is specified, read first sheet
if nargin == 1 || isempty(sheetName)
    sheetName = 1;
end

% If row start and end points are not specified, define defaults
if nargin <= 3
    startRow = 2;
    endRow = 250;
end

%% Import the data, extracting spreadsheet dates in MATLAB serial date number format (datenum)
[~, ~, raw, dateNums] = xlsread(workbookFile, sheetName, sprintf('A%d:E%d',startRow(1),endRow(1)),'' , @convertSpreadsheetDates);
for block=2:length(startRow)
    [~, ~, tmpRawBlock,tmpDateNumBlock] = xlsread(workbookFile, sheetName, sprintf('A%d:E%d',startRow(block),endRow(block)),'' , @convertSpreadsheetDates);
    raw = [raw;tmpRawBlock]; %#ok<AGROW>
    dateNums = [dateNums;tmpDateNumBlock]; %#ok<AGROW>
end

%% Replace date strings by MATLAB serial date numbers (datenum)
R = ~cellfun(@isequalwithequalnans,dateNums,raw) & cellfun('isclass',raw,'char'); % Find spreadsheet dates
raw(R) = dateNums(R);

%% Create output variable
data = reshape([raw{:}],size(raw));

%% Allocate imported array to column variable names
Date = data(:,1);
Open = data(:,2);
High = data(:,3);
Low = data(:,4);
Close = data(:,5);
```

Comment: how are you calling this function?

Comment: >>importfile(filename.xlsx) from command line.
After this, one variable gets displayed in the Workspace, i.e., ans. And this variable is a matrix of first column of the excel file, I am importing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `[Date,Open,High,Low,Close] = importfile('filename.xlsx');`

Comment: @Manganese please check the checkbox to indicate that you accept the answer. :)